# Why does "ls > out | cat < out" only output the first time I run it in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I am programming a Bash-like shell. I am having trouble understanding how this interaction works.

This command

```bash
ls > out | cat < out
```

only outputs the `ls` the first time I run it, and then nothing. In zsh it outputs everytime but not in Bash.

Comment: The order of execution of the commands in a pipeline is unpredictable. If `cat < out` runs before `ls > out`, there won't be anything for `cat` to read.

Comment: Also, `cat` can only read from the pipe or `out`, not both, in `bash`.

Comment: And `ls > out` will send nothing to the pipe

Comment: @Barmar Is it true that the order is unpredictable? When I run `rm -f out; ls -l > out | cat < out`, I always get `-bash: out: No such file or directory`. Doesn't that mean it runs `cat < out` first?

Comment: The shell opens the input and output files before it starts the child processes. That will be in a consistent order.

Comment: So you are deliberately trying to make a new shell syntax? None of the typical shells (bash, sh, ksh, zsh) will understand your command. The normal syntax would be `ls > out ; cat < out` . Note the semi-colon (`;`) that is separating the two commands. Good luck!

Comment: **cat < out** will be initiated and terminated before **ls -l > out** ... because the cat is not depending on the pipe ... because the redirect has overriden the pipe. for stream assignment. if zsh does not encounter the same issue, that is because it has logic that goes beyond basic command line parsing.

Comment: `zsh` has a `MULTIOS` option that lets multiple redirections apply to a command, rather than the last one simply superseding any previous redirections.

Comment: Don't tag it as _bash_ **and** _zsh_. Be specific, which shell you are using.

Comment: I know the command makes no sense, but my shell needs to replicate Bash on all type of commands. the order doesnt seem random tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to give the parser conflicting directives.
This is like telling someone to "Turn to the left on your right."

`<`, `>`, and `|` all instruct the interpreter to redirect I/O according to rules.

Look at this `bash` example:

```
$: echo two>two # creates a file named two with the word two in it
$: echo one | cat < two <<< "three" << END
four
END
four

$: echo one | cat < two <<< three
three

$: echo one | cat < two
two

$: echo one | cat
one
```

Understand that putting a pipe character (`|`) between commands links the output of the first one to the input of the second one, so *also* giving each an input/output redirection that conflicts with that is nonsensical.

```
ls | cat             # works - output of ls is input for cat
ls > out; cat < out  # works - ls outputs to out, then cat reads out 
ls > >(cat)          # works 
cat < <(ls)          # works
```

but `ls >out | cat` sends the output from `ls` to `out`, and then attaches the output of that operation (of which there is none, because it's already been captured) to `cat`, which exits with no input or output.

If what you wanted was to have the output both go to a file and to the console, then either use `ls > out; cat < out` which makes them separate operations, or try

```
ls | tee out
```

which explicitly splits the stream to both the file and stdout.